# Rolling a ball forward with AddForce depending on the track direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, direction, normals

I have a ball that moves forward alone, the player only has to turn left or right to get the gems and not falling off the road.

The problem is that I use a function called AddForce to push the ball forward but I don't know how to adapt the direction depending on the direction of the track. If there is a left turn for exemple, I want my ball to take the turn by it self an readapt to the track keeping the camera to follow behind.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sideSpeed * rb.velocity.magnitude / acceleration;

    if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= speedLimit)
    {
        rb.AddForce(0.0f, 0.0f, acceleration); // add vertical force
    }
    rb.AddForce(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f); // add horizontal force
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahX6C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddRelativeForce.html), to add force in the relative forward direction of the ball, so no matter which rotation the ball has, it always goes forward. Try something like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * sideSpeed * rb.velocity.magnitude / acceleration;

    if (rb.velocity.magnitude <= speedLimit)
    {
        rb.AddRelativeForce(0.0f, 0.0f, acceleration); // Add vertical force
    }

    rb.AddRelativeForce(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Add relative horizontal force
}
```

Hope this helps!